# How to determine which of the trig functions have horizontal and vertical asymptotes?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, asymptotics

1. Do any of the trigonometric functions $\sin x, \cos x, \tan x,
   \cot x, \sec x$, and $\csc x$ have horizontal asymptotes?
2. Do any of the trigonometric functions have vertical
   asymptotes? Where?

The answer for Q1 is 'No' whereas for Q2, it is 'Yes, $\tan x \space$ and $\space \sec x \space$ at $\space x = nπ + π/2 \space$ and $\space \cot x$ and $\space \csc x \space$ at $\space x = nπ, \space n = 0, ±1, ±2$, ...'

What formula and techniques should I use to prove that the two answers above are correct?
Any suggestion will be helpful!

Comment: For Q2: because tan x = sin(x)/cos(x) and the asymtotes are where the limit is infinity (so the denominator is 0). cos x is 0 at the points pi*n for some natural n. You can argue the same for sec x = 1/cos(x).

Comment: Let me just point out that if $p>0$, any function that’s $p$-periodic ($f(x+p)=f(x)$ holding for every $x$) can have no horizontal asymptote unless it’s constant.